# What happens when Smeargle cannot Sketch a move?

Tags: pokemon-go

I caught a Smeargle today following a photo bomb with my Lock-On / Focus Blast Registeel. The Smeargle I caught, to my surprise, knew Astonish / Focus Blast, not Lock-On. My suspicion is that Lock-On cannot be learnt by Smeargle, because Lock-On was introduced after Sketch.

My question is why did Smeargle learn Astonish? My guess is that it was a random move, but I cannot prove this nor find evidence online. None of the Pokemon I had used, caught or evolved recently knew that move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Smeargle cannot learn the move it tries to copy, it will simply learn a random move from its available move pool. This goes for both fast and charge moves.

While snapping pictures of Registeel this morning, I was lucky enough to be photobombed. Smeargle learned Karate Chop instead of Lock-On. This has happened to [other trainers](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/e4erdp/smeargle_does_not_have_lockon_on_photobomb/) as well.

Apparently (at the time of writing of the reddit thread at least) Smeargle could not learn Psystrike and learned Hydro Pump instead.

Another trainers Smeargle learned Blast Burn after photobombing a Lucario instead of learning its original charge move (my guess would be Aura Sphere, since Aura Sphere is a newer move introduced within the last year).